# C++ getnstr causes odd segmentation faults

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, ncurses

So I'm currently working on a project which uses `ncurses` for output and input. In this program, the user should be able to, for example, write his name. The issue I'm having is with `getnstr`, as it can cause some very weird and unexplainable segmentation faults. For example this code right here works fine as it is:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char *word;
    initscr();
    WINDOW *window = newwin(100, 100, 0, 0);
    nodelay(window, false);
    refresh();

    mvwgetnstr(window, 0, 0, word, 10);
    mvwprintw(window, 0, 0, "Word written is %s", word);

    wrefresh(window);
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

However if I only add a single string variable inside of the main function for example in the form of this:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string crashMe;

    char *word;
    initscr();
    WINDOW *window = newwin(100, 100, 0, 0);
    nodelay(window, false);
    refresh();

    mvwgetnstr(window, 0, 0, word, 10);
    mvwprintw(window, 0, 0, "Word written is %s", word);

    wrefresh(window);
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

It will instead have a segmentation fault on the first keypress you are doing with `getnstr`. I'm not sure if it's only on my computer or if I'm doing something horribly wrong with `ncurses` but I find it weird that initializing a string variable is causing the issue. The same issue can be reproduced by introducing an additional `char*` into the same brackets as the `getnstr`.

If anyone has any thoughts about this issue, I'd greatly appreciate hearing them. Idk if it might be a C related thing causing my segmentation faults. Either way, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking to read 10 characters into a pointer that points nowhere in particular. Try either `char word[10];` or `char *word = malloc(10);`

So why does that sometimes work? Your uninitialized pointer variable may have pointed to a writable memory area by accident. You were overwriting something somewhere, which may not always immediately crash.

I'm pretty sure that should have produced a compiler warning. Always compile with `-Wall` and pay attention to the output.